Complex Woolen Stitches, 3D Modeling Issues
I'm trying to make like this stitches with 3D but I failed. I'm trying many ways (see below) without success. How can I make it?
stitch circular pattern:

close view:

b&w colors:

stitches blend file
1st workflow on the left: overlapping horizontal and vertical mesh lines:

2nd workflow on the right: single knitting stitch, extended to a plane by 2 Array modifiers:


"I'm trying many ways but not success" Could you show us what you tried and why it did not satisfy your needs?

You get a better result if you model a little horseshoe or something that looks like a "Q" and make it 3D.
